# Double left brace including several lines in eqnarray with an arrow between

Tags: equations, arrows, brackets

I m trying to write two systems of equations with "left brace" separated with a long arrow as on the figure below.

[image]

I try with this kind of code but it doesnt work...The two systems are not aligned. One is at the bottom

```
\begin{equation}
    \left\{
    \begin{array}{ll}
        blabla1 \\
        \vspace{0.01cm} \\
        blabla2 \\
        \vspace{0.01cm} \\
        blabla 3 \\
    \end{array}
    \right.

\Longrightarrow

    \left\{
    \begin{array}{ll}
        blabla5 \\
        \vspace{0.01cm} \\
        blabla6 \\
        \vspace{0.01cm} \\
        blabla7 \\
    \end{array}
    \right.

\end{equation}\
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What do you mean by "it doen't work"? Errors, warnings, no output? We will have to see a compilable example of this. Appart of the very last slash and all those empty lines, your code runs fine for me.

Comment: Do _not_ leave blank lines in math environments: this will produce a bunch of errors and quite likely the "One is at the bottom" bit.

Comment: Works perfectly to me.

Comment: Perhaps a conflict with a package?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1):

Probably you want this? It uses the extensible arrows from `amsmath` and the `dcases`(=display style cases) environment from `mathtools` (a particularly useful extension of `amsmath`).

```
    \documentclass[11pt]{article}
    \usepackage{mathtools}

    \begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    \begin{dcases}
        \textsf{blabla 1} \\
        \textsf{blabla 2} \\
       \textsf{blabla 3} \end{dcases}
\xRightarrow{~\textsf{blabla4}~}
    \begin{dcases}
       \textsf{blabla 5} \\
        \textsf{blabla 6} \\
       \textsf{blabla 7}
    \end{dcases}
\end{equation}\

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With the "begin{alignat}", it works perfectly!

```
\begin{alignat*}{2}
\left\{ \begin{aligned}
& [[u]] (r) = u(r, \pi) - u(r, -\pi)\\
& [[v]] (r) = v(r, \pi) - v(r, -\pi)\\
& $[[$w$]]$ (r) = w(r$,$ \pi) - w(r$,$ -\pi)
\end{aligned}\right.
& \quad \xrightarrow{\mbox{\tiny{par symétrie}}}  \quad
& \left\{ \begin{aligned}
& [[u]]_{II} \neq 0, [[u]]_{III} = [[u]]_{I} = 0 \\
& [[v]]_{I} \neq 0, [[v]]_{III} = [[v]]_{II} = 0 \\
& [[w]]_{III} \neq 0, [[w]]_{II} = [[w]]_{I} = 0
\end{aligned}\right.
\end{alignat*}\
```